# How To Retrieve Data From List and Check Whether it contains certain values

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a tkinter entry box that lets users enter numbers separated by commas. The program stores the entry in a list. Now I want to check if the list contains a certain number or numbers. How would I go about doing that.

Thanks

P.S. If you need examples of code let me know

Comment: yes, always provide your code and what you have tried already.

Comment: You should post a code example and also post what you've tried to solve the problem so far.

Comment: You can try to use `in` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
if 3 in l:
    #do something
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> _list = [2, 3, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 6]
>>> 2 in _list
True
>>> all(x in _list for x in (2, 3, 5, 1))
True
>>> all(x in _list for x in (2, 3, 5, 1, 9))
False
```